# What's the benefit of this edit? (Added 2 spaces)

Tags: support, answers, editing

Someone edited an answer just to add two spaces.

Link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/58762/3

Why would someone do that and is this allowed?

Comment: No, it's totally not allowed and that guy should be banned ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The two extra spaces (and the subsequent line break) at the end of a line trigger a paragraph break in the rendered result. Without them, the image is rendered inline with the text, and since inline html content gets treated as though it's one line of text high, it makes that last line of text as high as the image, badly splitting the actual paragraph of text, making it harder to read/follow (see below).

As for whether this is allowed, yes, that's one of the founding philosophies of the stack exchange network, part forum, part Q&A, part wiki. So long as edits actually make improvements, they are encouraged (even with low rep, you can make edits, they'll just go into a review queue for others to double check). That being said, if you ever have someone make an edit that you don't think improves your post, you are free to roll it back.

---

**Before**

> [image]

**After**

> [image]